# Why doesn't ethanol conduct electricity?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polarity

As far I know ethanol is soluble in water in all proportions, and since water is polar it would imply that ethanol is also polar and the only possible polar group in ethanol is the -OH group.

Oxygen is much more electronegative than hydrogen, so oxygen has to attract the electron pair towards itself forming a polar compound. 
This means it should have to disassociate into ions in aqueous solution and conduct electricity but it doesn't.

In some other posts of the same site mentions, why ethanol doesn't disassociate much in water, but it doesn't explain why the ethanol is still soluble in water in all proportion even it is not get disassociating much.

Why?

Comment: Pure water isn't a very good conductor either...

Comment: Really, water itself isn't polar enough to dissociate much; why should ethanol be?

Comment: Neutral particles are by definition not charge carriers and can therefore not contribute directly to the conductivity of a solution. You need dissolved charge carriers, in the case of a pure solvent at low applied fields usually ions resulting from self-dissociation of the solvent molecules or some other charge transfer mechanism.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31507/electrical-conductivity-of-organic-solvents

Comment: For ethanol, the autoionization constant, at room temperature, is  $\mathrm 1.0 x 10^{-20}$. This is what I have seen in various places on the web, so it needs a serious reference, but it seems reasonable.

Comment: So the resistivity of pure ethanol at room temperature should be roughly 18 $\text{G}\Omega\cdot \text{cm}$, which is a thousand times higher than pure water at room temperature. This means a given potential applied to a pair of electrodes will result in currents a thousand times smaller that in water, ceteris paribus.

Answer (score -1):

Why should pure water and pure ethanol dissociate ? Substances get dissociated into ions if they win some stability in this process. NaCl is more stable in the dissociated state than in the covalent. In ionic NaCl, all atoms look like rare gases, and respect the octet rule. In a theoretically covalent structure, Na does not respect the octet rule. So it is less stable. 
But ethanol is made of atoms which all respect the octet rule. So why should they dissociate ?

Comment: If ethanol doesn't disassociate than why is it soluble in all proportions? Please explain